# Sending POST request rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, request, postman

I'm new in Ruby/Rails and I am trying to create simple API that will hold beer model (name and alcohol percent). I implemented API with rails gem rails-api but i have problem with sending POST request. I'm getting 400 ERROR due to bad syntax (using postman for sending requests).

I dont know what I am doing wrong. Here's my beers controller:

```
class BeersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_beer, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /beers
  # GET /beers.json
  def index
    @beers = Beer.all

    render json: @beers
  end

  # GET /beers/1
  # GET /beers/1.json
  def show
    render json: @beer
  end

  # POST /beers
  # POST /beers.json
  def create
    @beer = Beer.new(beer_params)

    if @beer.save
      render json: @beer, status: :created, location: @beer
    else
      render json: @beer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /beers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /beers/1.json
  def update
    @beer = Beer.find(params[:id])

    if @beer.update(beer_params)
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: @beer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /beers/1
  # DELETE /beers/1.json
  def destroy
    @beer.destroy

    head :no_content
  end

  private

    def set_beer
      @beer = Beer.find(params[:id])
    end

    def beer_params
      params.require(:beer).permit(:name, :percent)
    end
end
```

Hope you guys can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

When i print logs after this request i get this from heroku logs:

2015-04-06T11:51:40.715123+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/beer s" host=drinkapptest.herokuapp.com request_id=e4557a13-1391-4e30-ab8a-069e714b93 d0 fwd="89.164.165.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=400 bytes=264

Comment: That looks generally ok. Can you share the POST request you are making?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I am using POSTMAN but i cant post screenshot because of low reputation so here's screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/tzvdue4rd/

Comment: Either the request response or your log file should say why the request was refused

Comment: response is empty, but im not sure about logs? i should see some heroku logs since its deployed there?

Comment: heroku log doesnt say anything, this prints when i send post request: 2015-04-06T11:51:40.715123+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/beer
s" host=drinkapptest.herokuapp.com request_id=e4557a13-1391-4e30-ab8a-069e714b93
d0 fwd="89.164.165.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=400 bytes=264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `POST` from postman app should be structured to be something like this:

```
beer[name]       testing
beer[percent]    1
```

Comment: stil 400 bad request ://, any other idea?

Comment: Try without the quotes

Comment: can you pls send me screenshot of your request please

Comment: Thank's alot Vineeth, i was puting header Content-type: application/json, so that must of been problem. Its working now for me too :D, thank you once again. cheers

Comment: @itodor I would recommend you taking out the URL to your service from the comment.

Comment: Just did, pls just remove your screenshot comment too :D. Again appreciate all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this..

```
render json: { data: @beer, location: @beer, status: :created }
```